# How can an internal hard drive be made completely inaccessible for the system?

Tags: boot, kernel, hard-drive, udev

I've "rescued" my whole main system HDD onto another fresh drive (using a live CD, to be able to easier access `/` and `/usr` from X11), and now I'd like to pretend as if I had **physically removed** the old drive.
The reason is simple: since the target drive is an exact clone of the source drive (including UUIDs!), Ubuntu may easily get confused when trying to figure out what is what.
And no, I would not want to open the PC and unplug the cable: I would prefer to do this via a software solution.

This is why I'd like to make the source drive inaccessible, so that even `/dev/sdb` does no longer exist.
Those "tricks" mentioned in other answers that simply put the HDD to sleep (`hdparm -Y`) do not work here, because I've checked these possibilities and `gparted` still "knew" about the old drive.
I would not consider the solution I am looking for to be working until `gparted` really skips from `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdc`.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to "to pretend as if I had physically removed" a disk is to disconnect it:

1. Power down your system
2. Open your system, wearing a grounded anti-static strap.
3. Physically remove the Power cable from the disk. Be very careful, and remember how to replace the cable. Removing the Data cable is not needed. Leave the disk in place.
4. Put your system back together.

If the disk is powered, and physically connected to the bus, it MUST be visible to the BIOS, and, when it is booted, Ubuntu. Otherwise, you would complain "Ubuntu cannot see my disk!".

Comment: There! This will be a classic -1 for you because you should never treat users like complete idiots ("*remember how to replace the (power) cable*"). If this was supposed to demonstrate your (questionable) sense of humor, you may consider this an __epic fail__.

Comment: @syntaxerror: So you dislike my answer. Do you have a better one? I wrote this one based on experience, having done something similar.

Comment: Fair enough, but then don't formulate it in such a comedic way. BTW, learn to read questions thoroughly and don't just skim over them:  *I would not want to open the PC and unplug the cable*. Frankly, when I read your answer the first time, I seriously thought you had a hard night-out and posted while still drunk!

Comment: @syntaxerror: I considered and reconsidered adding the "remember how to replace the power cable" part. I decided to add it because, over my 48-year computer career, and can recall a couple of times when I wished somebody had made that point to me.

Comment: HAHA, so it must be an age thing I guess. I occasionally come across these "IT methusalems"; and when discussing with them, it always feels as if I was trying to make a Red Indian in the 1880s accept "our" point of view. Or perhaps, left-wing folks trying to convince republicans that their thinking is set in concrete, and that it is going to make things worse than before ;-) A *bike-shed discussion* is an Internet term for it.

Comment: No, it's an "experience thing". Your "Red Indian" remark seems a tad racist.

Comment: (Hah, I had to expect that, hadn't I? :P) This may occur to you that way. But no, I'm against stupid (pseudo-)politically correct terms like "Native American". Some pc paranoiac once coined it, declaring all other terms as "racist" from now on. And all media jumped on the bandwagon immediately. *This* is the actual problem: dictating what may be said and what may not. And I've always objected against this form of dictatorship.